# How to use $in with the _id

Tags: mongodb

How can I use _id in $in.

```
array('name' => array(
     '$in' => array('name1', 'name2')
))
```

This is how $in is used in mongodb. But I don't know how to use $in with _id.

I used

```
    array('_id' => array(
     '$in' => new MongoId(array(My Ids))
   ))
```

But it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to provide an **array of MongoId**'s and not an MongoId of array (which is not possible).

So you have to preprocess you array before query or keep these ids as MongoId

Answer (score 0):

you can use array_map for that, or foreach.